# creating dataframe from aperiodic data. (realigning timestamps) [Pandas Python]

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have some irregularly timestamped data that looks like:

```
                    Oil Pres.  Out ppm  Ratio   In  Out  Inlet psi  Bag psi  \
Date                                                                           
2013-12-10 19:01:00         56        0      0  455  462       2.26     0.44   
2013-12-10 20:00:00         55        0      0  450  456      10.91     0.73   
2013-12-10 20:33:00         55        0      0  443  452       9.24     0.54   
2013-12-10 22:00:00         54        0      0  440  449       8.16     0.62   
2013-12-10 22:31:00         54        0      0  436  445      10.29     0.49
```

How could I align the data between two dates (EX: 2013-12-10 18:00:00 and 2013-12-11 00:00:00 at 20 minute intervals such that it appeared as below:

```
                Oil Pres.  Out ppm  Ratio   In  Out  Inlet psi  Bag psi  \
Date               
2013-12-10 18:00:00         NaN...
2013-12-10 18:20:00                                                  
2013-12-10 18:40:00
2013-12-10 19:00:00         56        0      0  455  462       2.26     0.44   
2013-12-10 19:20:00
2013-12-10 19:40:00
2013-12-10 20:00:00         55        0      0  450  456      10.91     0.73   
2013-12-10 20:20:00
2013-12-10 20:40:00         55        0      0  443  452       9.24     0.54   
2013-12-10 21:00:00
2013-12-10 21:20:00
2013-12-10 21:40:00
2013-12-10 22:00:00         54        0      0  440  449       8.16     0.62   
2013-12-10 22:20:00
2013-12-10 22:40:00         54        0      0  436  445      10.29     0.49  
2013-12-10 23:00:00
2013-12-10 23:20:00
2013-12-10 23:40:00
2013-12-11 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe:

```
df.resample( '20T', how='mean' )
```

alternatively, you may do:

```
idx = pd.date_range( start='2013-12-10 18:00:00',
                     end='2013-12-11 00:00:00',
                     freq='20T' )
df.reindex( idx, method='ffill', limit=1 )
```

Comment: FYI: `mean` is the default, so no need to specify it in this case.

Comment: There are more columns in the data that are not shown above, and using this code causes the non-numeric columns to drop off. Also, how would I pad the head and tail ends with the specified timeframe?

Comment: @BrianLeach use `reindex` and `date_range` as in my edits above

Comment: @ behzed.nouri: I am receiving a "AssertionError: Block ref_items must be BlockManager items" from the reindex line

Comment: @BrianLeach what is your pandas version? where exactly this exception in thrown?

Comment: @behzad.nouri I am using Pandas version 0.11.0. The Error I am getting is described in the following stack trace http://pastebin.com/HE5exB6j

Comment: @YickLeung, Please keep comments relevant to the question at hand. It will make it easier for other users to navigate the questions.

Comment: @BrianLeach pandas is under heavy development, if it is possible for you update it to current stable version. i will look into the stack trace once i get the chance

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43286/discussion-between-brian-leach-and-behzad-nouri)